# How to programmatically change included layout? Android Studio, Scrolling Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have activity_scrolling.xml, content_scrolling.xml, one_more_content.xml
In activity_scrolling.xml:

```
<include="@layout/content_scrolling" />
```

How can I change the included layout to one_more_content.xml programmaticaly in ScrollingActivity.java?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ViewFlipper` for this

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <include android:id="@+id/view1" layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />
    <include android:id="@+id/view2" layout="@layout/one_more_content" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

and then update the UI using this

```
binding.viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
```

If you are not using view binding, use this instead

```
ViewFlipper vFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
vFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
```

Comment: i think you confused data binding and view binding, so i've updated your answer for you